# Get UWP theme colors in C# code

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is it possible to get the current Windows 10 theme colors in UWP app with C# code?

I have found `Application.RequestedTheme` [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme) but it only tells me if dark och light theme is being used, not the actual colors.

I have seen XAML markup that references theme colors but would like to know the RGB value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [XAML theme resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx), and you can use

`Application.Current.Resources["SystemAccentColor"]`